# Looking for a tool to create C-arrays with data from a file

Tags: c++

Input: filename.bin

Output:

```
char file_filename_data[] = {
0x47, 0x45, 0x54, 0x20, 0x2f, 0x63, 0x61, 0x6d, 
0x2e, 0x68, 0x74, 0x6d, 0x6c, 0x20, 0x48, 0x54, 
0x54, 0x50, 0x2f, 0x31, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x0d, 0x0a, 
0x48, 0x6f, 0x73, 0x74, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x79, 0x6d, 
0x61, 0x70, 0x2e, 0x64, 0x79, 0x6e, 0x64, 0x6e, 
0x73, 0x2e, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x67, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x55, 
0x73, 0x65, 0x72, 0x2d, 0x41, 0x67, 0x65, 0x6e, 
0x74, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x6f, 0x7a, 0x69, 0x6c, 
...
}; // This is the data from the file "filename.bin"

size_t file_filename_size = 1234;
```

I want to store some text files inside an executable file. I am using CMake and building C++ project both in linux and in windows.

Thank you!

Comment: Uhm... *what have you tried?*

Comment: It's still not clear what do yo want to accomplish. What is the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`xxd`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xxd1.html) is what you're looking for. Example call could be:

```
xxd -i filename.bin data_output.h
```

`data_output.h` would have the contents of:

```
unsigned char in_file[] = {
  0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f
};
unsigned int in_file_len = 5;
```

Comment: Whoa, interesting find, didn't know about that tool.

Comment: Isn't `xxd` for Linux? What about Windows? Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Note that this isn't good except for small files, since compile time gets outrageously large with large constant arrays.  There are some tools around to directly create object files, and on Win32 you have an additional option of embedded "resources".

Comment: @afaolek: If you have installed MSYS with MinGW you should have access to this program.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you can append the information at the end of the file. It's a hack, but it's used by many apps - installers, python freeze (I think), lots of demo coders used it in the past.

Basically just do (CMD.EXE)

echo "Blah" >> myexefile.exe

How would you find this info? Well be inventive - maybe store a unique magic cookie, or just always put the last 4 or 8 bytes to tell you the size of the file, so you can find where it begins.